# user deselect, then remove item from array and arrange depends on how they were selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I remove item in an array if the user changes its selected options from select element? and at the same time arrange the selected options on how they were selected by the user. for example they were selected as 3, 1, 4, 2.

this is my code in javascript

```
    <script>
            var selected_id = [];
            $(document).on('click','.clickable',function(e){
            selected_id.push($(this).attr('id'));
            console.log(selected_id);
            }).get().join(", "); 
            $("#gen-btn").click(function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                 $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('reports/generate_imported'); ?>",
                    data: {selected_id: selected_id},
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(result){
                        alert(result);
                    }
                }); 
                return false; 

             });

        </script>
```

here is my code in view page

```
            <select class="form-control reports" name="cols[]" multiple="multiple" id="cols[]" required="required">
                        <option id="1" class="clickable" value="1">item 1</option>
                        <option id="2" class="clickable" value="2">item 2</option>
                        <option id="3" class="clickable" value="3">item 3</option>
                        <option id="4" class="clickable" value="4">item 4</option></select>
```

thanks to @itsgoingdown, got my desired behavior of removing item from array, but I want them to be arranged on how they were selected. like for example 3, 1, 4, 2.

Comment: Basically you want your `selected_id` array to contain only the last selected value?

Comment: nope, hard to explain but here's my thought... my coding has a bug, when the user selected for example 2,3,4 but suddenly changes his/her mind and selected only 1, the array is still 2,3,4 and 1(which he/she selected). how am i going to remove the 2,3,4?

Comment: check my answer, I think it has your desired behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
  var selected_id = [];
  var selected_ord=[];
        $(document).on('click','.clickable',function(e){
          
          var ops= $(this).parent().find(":selected").length;
          
         if($(e.target).is(':selected')){
            

         selected_ord.push($(e.target).attr('id'));
            
 selected_id=selected_ord.slice(selected_ord.length-ops, selected_ord.length);          
          
         }
           
            
     else {
      
           var toRemove=selected_ord.lastIndexOf($(e.target).attr('id'));
         
         selected_ord.splice(toRemove ,1);
       var index = selected_id.indexOf($(e.target).attr('id'));  
       selected_id.splice(index, 1);
       
     } 
     
          console.log(selected_id); 
          
            }).get().join(", "); 
            $("#gen-btn").click(function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                 $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('reports/generate_imported'); ?>",
                    data: {selected_id: selected_id},
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(result){
                        alert(result);
                    }
                }); 



                return false; 

             });
             $("#gen-btn").click(function(){
                selected_id.length = 0;
             });
```

Here is the testing example
[Example](http://jsbin.com/fipana/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: I didn't noticed that your code arranging in ascending. :D do you have another way of arranging them depends on user selection? for example he/she selected 3,1,4,2?

Comment: @En E el, you mean, if the selects multiple values, you want them to be contained in the array by order, which he select first-> last ?

Comment: sorry for my poor explanation. :D I want them to be arrange on how they were selected. like for example the option he/she selected  3, 1, 4 and 2.

Comment: I think you're having a hard time of editing it :( sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Yes, it is much complex than it looks. Got stuck when deselecting and selecting again multiple ops. Will send you the code in the morning, if you don't figure it out

Comment: I'll wait for your answer tomorrow. still can't figure it out.

Comment: @En E el a serious head-beater :D here is the code: http://jsbin.com/fipana/edit?js,console,output

I will edit the above post

Comment: this so great! :D thank you so much. I really appreciate your kindness. have a great day to you and God bless. :D

Answer (score 0):

Let say:

```
var selected_id = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Firstly, on click event you need to search on array (selected_id) using the value/id you get from $(this).attr('id'):

```
selected_id.indexOf("1"); # this will return 0
```

Meaning if you get value greater than or equal to zero (>= 0), item is exists in array (selected_id)

Finally, you can remove it by setting the index like:

```
selected_id.remove(1);

return value is:  ["1", "3"]
```

Try to make a function if you like:

```
function deleteFromArray(params_array, index){
  var result = new Array();
  for(var i in params_array){
    if(params_array[i] == index){
      continue;
    }
    result.push(params_array[i]);
  }
  return result;
}


deleteFromArray(selected_id , 0);
returns: selected_id = ["2", "3"];
```

Comment: is this will arrange the selected options depends on the user selection?